# Pip says that pymongo has been installed, but doesn't show it as installed

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, virtualenv, pymongo

I'm trying to install pymongo in a virtual environment, and pip says that it's installed, but it doesn't appear to be:

```
(venv)$ ./myapp.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./myapp.py", line 5, in <module>
    import myAppMongo
  File "/home/me/python/myapp/myAppMongo.py", line 4, in <module>
    from pymongo import MongoClient
ImportError: No module named 'pymongo'
```

I've installed pymongo:

```
(venv)$ pip --no-cache install pymongo
Collecting pymongo
  Downloading pymongo-3.2.tar.gz (473kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 475kB 18.3MB/s
Installing collected packages: pymongo
  Running setup.py install for pymongo ... done
Successfully installed pymongo
```

But it doesn't appear in pip's freeze output:

```
(venv)$ pip freeze |grep -ic pymongo
0
```

I'm running Amazon's linux with their python 3 packages:

```
(venv)$ sudo yum list installed|grep -i python3
python34.x86_64                   3.4.3-1.30.amzn1              @amzn-main
python34-devel.x86_64             3.4.3-1.30.amzn1              @amzn-main
python34-libs.x86_64              3.4.3-1.30.amzn1              @amzn-main
python34-pip.noarch               6.1.1-1.21.amzn1              @amzn-main
python34-setuptools.noarch        12.2-1.30.amzn1               @amzn-main
python34-test.x86_64              3.4.3-1.30.amzn1              @amzn-main
python34-tools.x86_64             3.4.3-1.30.amzn1              @amzn-main
python34-virtualenv.noarch        12.0.7-1.12.amzn1             @amzn-updates
```

How can I get this working?

Comment: Does `./myapp.py` define an interpreter on its first line?

Comment: What if you try `python myapp.py`?

Comment: Yes, `$ head -n 1 myapp.py
#!/home/me/python/myapp/venv/bin/python`

Comment: @PeterWood, either way, I get the `No module named 'pymongo'` error.

Comment: I don't see the `(venv)` prefix in your `$ pip freeze [...]` example. Did you run the command from the virtual environment and forgot to copy the prefix or did you not run it from the virtual environment?

Comment: What happens if you just run python and do ```import pymongo``` from interactive interpreter prompt?

Comment: @NiklasR I did, and I forgot to include it. I've edited it in to avoid future confusion.

Comment: @MadWombat I get the same `No module named 'pymongo'` error.

Comment: As people mentioned, chances are you are trying to use pip from a different python version. You want to make really sure. Do `which pip`, look at the pip file and check that they python binary in its first line is the same as the one returned by `which python`. Then try to use full path to pip to install pymongo, run python using full path and try `import pymongo` again. See if you find a problem in the process.

Comment: @MadWombat `(venv)$ head -n 1 $(which pip)
#!/home/me/python/myapp/venv/bin/python3.4` I have run them with the full paths to my virtual environment and I get the same behavior as above.

Comment: FWIW, using easy_install worked fine :\

Comment: @MadWombat also I've installed several other packages in the virtual environment and they all worked as expected.

Comment: @IgniFerroque I have the exact same issue with the package `lsm-db` on my ec2. I asked it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57105227/cannot-pip-install-package-in-virtualenv-on-ec2). Did you ever find the reason and the solution?

Comment: I never found the solution :(

Answer (score 1):

Try using `pip3` to install pymongo instead of `pip`!

Comment: It didn't seem to make a difference, I think they're both the same thing. Running `which pip` and `which pip3` shows they're both in the bin folder of my virtual environment. Also, `pip --version` and `pip3 --version` shows the same version.

Comment: and you're running these commands in the virtual environment, correct?

Comment: `#!/home/me/python/myapp/venv/bin/python3`?

Comment: `(venv)$ head -n 1 $(which pip) #!/home/me/python/myapp/venv/bin/python3.4`

Answer (score 0):

Let’s start from the beginning:

Type this and paste here the response:

```
type pip
```

Comment: `$ type pip
pip is hashed (/home/me/python/myapp/venv/bin/pip)`

Comment: That’s the correct pip. `python -V` must return `Python 3.3.X`, right?

Comment: `(venv)$ python --version
Python 3.4.3`

Comment: OK, everything looks OK. What if you run `pip` without `--no-cache`? `pip install pymongo`

Comment: As shown in my initial question, that's the way I was running it in an attempt to eliminate the cache as a possible source of the problem.

Comment: Well… I’ve tried, but everything seems OK. I have no more ideas. Sorry.

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if your virtual environment was somehow not set up correctly?

do both

```
$ which python
```

and

```
$ which pip
```

Show you that the commands are being run from within the venv?

Comment: They do show the correct paths to the virtual environment.